# CSS Position absolute not working with relative parent

Tags: html, css

I have a problem. In my angular project I have the following code:

```css
.portfolio-summary-container {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
}

.portfolio-summary {
  display: inline-flex;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.portfolio-summary .section {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 25%;
  border: #c2c2c2 solid 1px;
}

.portfolio-summary .section-operator {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(25% - 17px);
  margin-top: 23px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: #b9b9b9 solid 1px;
  color: #808080;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  background-color: white;
}

.portfolio-summary .section .price {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.portfolio-summary .section .description {
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #808080
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio-summary-container">
<div class="portfolio-summary" *ngIf="portfolio">
  <div class="section">
    <div class="price">$10.00</div>
    <div class="description">AVAILABLE</div>
  </div>
  <div class="section-operator">+</div>
  <div class="section">
    <div class="price">$12.31</div>
    <div class="description">TOTAL ALLOCATED </div>
  </div>
  <div class="section-operator">+</div>
  <div class="section">
    <div class="price">$0.73</div>
    <div class="description">PROFIT</div>
  </div>
  <div class="section-operator">=</div>
  <div class="section">
    <div class="price">$23.04</div>
    <div class="description">EQUITY</div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

But I am trying to put the `<div class="section-operator">+</div>` between every section, so it would look like this:
[image]

I read that I need to give the parent: `position: relative;`, so thats why I created the `portfolio-summary-container`. The container is sticking to the bottom and the inner div has the `position: relative;` property, but this isn't working for some reason??? How can I get the result from the photo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can position each operator separately. I added `z-index` for the operators to be in the foreground.

```css
.portfolio-summary {
  display: inline-flex;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
}

.portfolio-summary .section {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 25%;
  border: #c2c2c2 solid 1px;
}

.portfolio-summary .section-operator {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 23px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: #b9b9b9 solid 1px;
  color: #808080;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 2;
}

.portfolio-summary .section .price {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.portfolio-summary .section .description {
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #808080
}

#op1 {
  left: calc(25% - 17px);
}
#op2 {
  left: calc(50% - 17px);
}
#op3 {
  left: calc(75% - 17px);
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio-summary" *ngIf="portfolio">
  <div class="section">
    <div class="price">$10.00</div>
    <div class="description">AVAILABLE</div>
  </div>
  <div class="section-operator" id="op1">+</div>
  <div class="section">
    <div class="price">$12.31</div>
    <div class="description">TOTAL ALLOCATED </div>
  </div>
  <div class="section-operator" id="op2">+</div>
  <div class="section">
    <div class="price">$0.73</div>
    <div class="description">PROFIT</div>
  </div>
  <div class="section-operator" id="op3">=</div>
  <div class="section">
    <div class="price">$23.04</div>
    <div class="description">EQUITY</div>
  </div>
</div>
```